# Issue when aligning the drop down boxes using bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap in my application. I am having a form which contains multiple drop down boxes which are placed inline. The width of the container containing the form is `col-lg-12` and is taking the entire screen. Because of the data inside the drop down the last two drop downs are displayed in the second line. I tried giving the `max-width` property of the `select` box to `50%`. The drop down width reduces but the margin still remains the same. I am not goot at bootstrap. Please let me know where I am going wrong. I am posting the code below:

```
<form novalidate role="form" name="filterForm" class="form-inline">
  <div ng-repeat="criteria in criterias">
    <div class="m-b">
       <div class="form-group s-b">
         <span>Country</span>
           <select class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in country" name="country" ng-model="classification.country">
           </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group s-b">
           <span>State</span>
             <select ng-options="item for item in state" class="form-control" name="state" ng-model="criteria.state"  style="max-width:50%">
             </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group s-b">
            <span>City</span>
              <select class="form-control"  ng-options="item for item in Cities"  name="account" ng-model="criteria.city" style="max-width:50%;">
              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group s-b">
            <span>Predicate</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="account" ng-model="criteria.predicate">
               <option value="matches">Matches</option>
               <option value="not-matches">Not Matches</option>
             </select>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group s-b">
             <span>Value</span>
             <select class="form-control" name="account" ng-model="criteria.value"  style="min-width:100px;">
             </select>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
             <span>
               <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pad-btn" type="submit" ng-click="addCriteria()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
               </button>
               <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pad-btn" type="submit" ng-click="deleteCriteria(criteria)"><i
                        class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
             </span>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pad-btn align-center" type="submit" ng-click="searchParams(filterForm)">Submit
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning pad-btn align-center" type="submit" ng-click="resetFilter()">Reset
                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i></button>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try adding a class

Since your data is too big you should try adding a class that modifies the position of the dropdowns, since they are absolute they should be easy to move around to where you want.

## Explanation of bootsraps column system

If you set your class `col-xs-12` it will be bull width all the way from mobile to big desktop

If you set your class to `col-xs-12 col-lg-6` then xs, sm and md will all be full width but lg will be half width.

try using [shoe lace](http://shoelace.io/) to model your column setup.

### Note

You should check out [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) since you're using angular.js. It removed the use of jQuery so you don't run into any compatibility issues or strange bugs.